# Adsense in IFRAME

Tags: ajax, iframe, adsense

I've created an entirely AJAX-based web app, however Adsense seems unable to generate any relevant ads for the AJAX-delivered content.

In an effort to get to show relevant ads, I created an I-Frame that would display a cache file containing a hard copy of the AJAX-fetched content in an html format and included the adsense.js script inside it.

Here's an example:

```
adsenseexample.html 


<html>
<head>
<title>User Cache</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:200px;">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 200;
google_ad_height = 200;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
(This is where the cached content is. It's not visible to the user but 
a complete duplicate of what they are viewing. It's in
 plain text with no pictures for faster loading).
</head>
</body>
```

Which is loaded into an iframe:

```
<iframe src="adsenseexample.html"> </iframe>
```

Anybody know why I'm still not getting any relevant ads. Is this method flawed from the get go?

Comment: Wait, so the ads are showing up but they don't seem relevant?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly it.  For instance, I created a test account which has  content about computers/tech delivered by AJAX. Like I explained above, the adense.html would contain the plain text version of all that content and is loaded into the IFRAME. Unfortunately, instead of relevant ads I get ads about that seem to be based on the non-AJAX delivered content like the site name.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, have you tried passing params to your iframe src such as keyword, description from the referral http request? You will then want to add the keywords param and description to the meta tags.

Answer (score -1):

Google states in their ToS that IFRAMES are not to be used with Adsense.